# JUnit test - asset or verify (or both) on a mock object?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I am playing around writing a JUnit test for some beans I have defined in my code, in order to learn about spring configuration via java annotations. The test code looks like this:

```
public class FooTest {

    @MockBean
    private Baz baz; //injected

    @MockBean
    private Qux qux; //injected

    public void testBar() {
        Foo foo = new Foo(baz);
        Qux reponse = foo.bar();
        // verify or assert?
    }

}
```

And the other classes are defined like this:

```
@Component
class Foo {

    Baz baz;

    @Autowired
    Foo(Baz baz) {
        this.baz = baz
    }

    Qux bar() {
        baz.waldo();
        baz.fred();
        return baz.newQux();
    }
}

@Component
class Baz {
    //...
}
```

As you can see in my JUnit test, I return a `Qux` response from the mocked `Qux` bean in the `FooTest` class. It got me thinking about testing the `bar` method in class `Foo`. I see 3 options here and was wondering what would be considered best practice?

1. Do an assertEquals on the `response` in test method `testBar` on the `qux` instance variable in `FooTest`.
2. Do the above but also do a `verify` on the `baz` instance in `FooTest` that `waldo` and `fred` were also called? Or are these verify calls superfluous, since the `baz` is returned, I assume they were called?
3. Do 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a possibility to do *Assert*, do it. In this case you will check the actual value that method returns after it was invoked.

*Verify* only checks that method was called. This is more useful when you call some method and you want to check that another method was called inside, but you couldn't do it based on the return object. In your case you return the whole object, thus, from my point of you, you should be able to use assert.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to define what happens when these statements are executed.

```
 baz.waldo();  
 baz.fred();  
 baz.newQux();
```

Since baz is a mock.

Secondly you have to do verify to make sure all the methods are called. You can also do assert. But first you need to define what has to be retuened when `baz.newQux()` is called. And check the response of `foo.bar()` if this is same as what you have defined.